# Dynamically added ng-form and validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a directive with template containing ng-form:

```
<ng-form name="autocompleteForm">
  <div class="form-group" show-errors>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.val.value" name="autocompleteField" required>

    <div class="messages" ng-messages="autocompleteForm.autocompleteField.$error">
      <span class="help-block" ng-message="required">Please, select the value</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-form>
```

And i add this form dynamically using ng-repeat. Everything - form itself, validation - works, but there is one annoying thing: after form is added it's $invalid and error message is shown. Not sure why it's happening and how to fix this. Here is forms's object after form is added:

```
{  
   "$error":{  
      "required":[  
         {  
            "$validators":{  

            },
            "$asyncValidators":{  

            },
            "$parsers":[  

            ],
            "$formatters":[  
               null
            ],
            "$viewChangeListeners":[  

            ],
            "$untouched":true,
            "$touched":false,
            "$pristine":true,
            "$dirty":false,
            "$valid":false,
            "$invalid":true,
            "$error":{  
               "required":true
            },
            "$name":"autocompleteField",
            "$options":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "$name":"autocompleteForm",
   "$dirty":false,
   "$pristine":true,
   "$valid":false,
   "$invalid":true,
   "$submitted":false,
   "autocompleteField":{  
      "$validators":{  

      },
      "$asyncValidators":{  

      },
      "$parsers":[  

      ],
      "$formatters":[  
         null
      ],
      "$viewChangeListeners":[  

      ],
      "$untouched":true,
      "$touched":false,
      "$pristine":true,
      "$dirty":false,
      "$valid":false,
      "$invalid":true,
      "$error":{  
         "required":true
      },
      "$name":"autocompleteField",
      "$options":null
   }
}
```

Found some blogs writing about dynamically added forms ([like this one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform)) and they have same behavior also. Is this default angular's way to go? Or there are some options to prevent "initial validation"?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the ng-if directive on your messages container to only show it if the form has been submitted like so:

```
<div class="messages" ng-messages="autocompleteForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="autocompleteForm.$submitted">
    <span class="help-block" ng-message="required">Please, select the value</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ErikSvedin for pointing to right direction - i just added one more condition:
`ng-if="autocompleteForm.autocompleteField.$touched || autocompleteForm.$submitted"`